# NUnit GUI Runner and Apartment State

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, watin, apartment-state

How do you set the apartment state in the NUnit GUI runner? I'm trying to run a single NUnit test with WatiN and I'm getting the message:

> MyNamespace.LoginTests.CanLogin:
>   System.Threading.ThreadStateException : The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

Comment: http://houseofbilz.com/archive/2008/10/14/getting-your-nunit-tests-to-run-as-sta.aspx

Comment: @adrianbanks Should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add some configuration to your assembly's app.config file (if you don't have once, create a new one) to tell NUnit to run as STA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
            <section name="TestRunner" 
                     type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <NUnit>
        <TestRunner>
            <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        </TestRunner>
    </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

([original source](http://houseofbilz.com/archive/2008/10/14/getting-your-nunit-tests-to-run-as-sta.aspx))

Answer (score 23):

Starting with NUnit 2.5, use [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute in your tests.